# Trying to update records by scheduling an apex class. However, I'm getting CPU Timeout Error with the code below. Am I suppose to use maps?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, map

```
List<Deal__c> records = [
        SELECT Name FROM Deal__c WHERE CloseDate__c < TODAY AND RecordType.Name = 'Franchise' AND (StageName__c != 'Servicing' OR StageName__c != 'Closed Lost')
    ];

    for (Deal__c record : records)
    {
        record.Close_Date_In_The_Past__c = true;
    }

      update records;
```

Above is my code and I'm getting errors when I launch it. It states that CPU time is too long. How would I use maps for this code?

Comment: Maybe use a batch job for this

Comment: How many items in the `records` list?  What triggers/workflow are running on the `Deal__c` object?  These will define how much CPU will be used.

Comment: The code you've provided isn't the heart of your issue, and using a map instead of a list wouldn't improve the performance. As Nick Cook as alluded to, it's a combination of the number of records you're working on and all of the work that is being done for those records via triggers, workflow, processes, validation, etc... If you can capture a debug log in the developer console, using the "analysis" perspective can help you a better idea of where the problem actually lies (is it a triple nested loop somewhere? or perhaps your triggers are being run more times than they should?)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response everyone. I think it's the amount of records that causing this to slow down. I have over 10,000 records in this object... I'm relatively you to the developer side of things so it's a bit of challenge so far.

Comment: Maybe you can do a data load to update historical records, and then when this code is running as a schedule there will be less records each time.  I'm assuming you've got a daily schedule set up for this to run?